# fetch in local json file not working on build time but only works in development mode

Tags: javascript, vite

I'm working on a vanilla javascript project bundled with vitejs everything works fine in development mode however when i run build and preview it with live server, fetching on local json data is not working.

[image]

here's the code I'm working on

loadData.js

```
const initData = {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  mode: "cors",
  cache: "default",
};
const requestData = new Request("./api/portfolioData.json", initData);

export const loadData = async function fetchData() {
  const response = await fetch(requestData);
 
  const data = await response.json();
  if (!response.ok) {
    return new Error("Not found", response.status);
  }
  return data;
};
```

UI project.js

```
import { loadData } from "../../services/data/loadData";
function Project() {
  loadData()
    .then((data) => {
      let placeholder = document.querySelector(".project-list");
      let out ="";
      for (let item of data) {
        out += `<div class="flip-card" tabindex=${item.id}>
    <div class="flip-card-inner">
      <div class="flip-card-front">
        <img src=${item.image} alt="" />
        <h3>${item.title}</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="flip-card-back">
        <h3>
          Tech use <i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-layer-group"></i>
          <br />
          <span>${item.techStack}</span>
        </h3>
        <p>
          <span>Description:</span>
          ${item.description}
        </p>
        <span class="demo"
          ><a href=${item.demo} target="_blank"
            >demo<i class="fa-solid fa-globe"></i
          ></a>
          <a
            href=${item.repo}
            target="_blank"
            >repo<i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i
          ></a>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>`;
      }
      placeholder.innerHTML = out;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

export default Project;
```

I tried to google for solution but there's no luck that works on my case.

i tried to add full path but i'm getting a cors error.
`const requestData = new Request("https://localhost:5173/api/portfolioData.json", initData);`

Comment: This is because when you deploy your frontend, are you deploying on the same server as backend. 404 means api was not found. You need to give proper path in fetch for it to work on live server. Since your api is on https you cannot make a call from http, you will have CORS issue. If you are different server altogether than check how share enable resource sharing on your backend

Comment: hello @Soheb i dont have any server or backend. the file is also in the frontend directory.

Comment: Would it be possible to share your json code?I see a syntax error in the console

Comment: here's the file https://github.com/dkeptsman/projectfort/blob/main/api/portfolioData.json